# Is it possible to have a GitLab CICD pipeline for Azure Snowflake DB?

Tags: azure, gitlab, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there anyone out here who has implemented CI/CD with GitLab for Azure Snowflake? Is this even possible?

Our DB development is growing fast and it's turning out to be challenging experience to develop, maintain and deploy.

We have Visual Studio Code IDE which is now bound to a Git repository who's branches I would like to point to Prod, Dev and Test depending on commits to respective branches.? Also, is it even possible to have something like a Config.sql similar to SQLCMD in SQL Server or Application.properties in a Java Springboot project, where, one can maintain 3 different config files with environment specific variables whose values can be substituted dynamically depending on the BUILD step of the CICD pipeline? I want (at least now) to keep database and schema names as config variables which will be different on where one deploys.

Comment: Is there a way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install and configure snowsql tool as part of your CICD pipeline. Snowsql for Snowflake is the same as sqlcmd for SQL Server.

[Installing snowsql](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-install-config.html)

[Configuring snowsql](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-config.html)

Comment: Hi, are you aware of any guide that runs through the entire process of setting it up which could help newbies with GitLab?

Comment: Hi @Anton, I went through the guides that you shared. It is still difficult to visualize that work-flow which I am thinking of. Let's say we have 3 config files ( dev-config.sql, qa-config.sql, prod-config.sql) and we use either of these to build and the code by substituting the parameters while commiting to DEV, QA and PROD branches in GIT. How do I go about and do it? Also, there doesn't seem to be any straightforward guides or articles explaining this use-case if someone has done this before.